# Python won't compare strings correctly?

Tags: string, variables, python-3.x

I am trying to make a basic password system using a text file, which the program reads from and assigns it to a variable. This variable is the one that will be compared with the user input. For some reason, even though the strings I know are exactly the same (I even copied and pasted the string from the text file into the input) it will result in the program telling me the password is incorrect. Here is the code:

```
import time

file = open("passwordfile.txt", "r")
localPass = file.readline()
userAttempt = 0
print (localPass)
localPassTest = localPass

    def enterScreen():
        print (" ")
        print ("You are in the program!")


for x in range (0, 3):
    userPass = input ("Enter password: ")
    if userPass == localPassTest:
        print (" ")
        print ("Correct password!")
        break
        enterScreen()
    else:
        print ("Incorrect password!")
```

Comment: You probably have issues with whitespace, try looking at `repr(localPass)` vs. `repr(userPass)` and consider adding in a `.strip()`.

Comment: I created password.txt with `pAssword` saved in file. Ran your code (fixed indent for def enterScreen()) everything thing worked perfect. I'm not sure what your issue is. Maybe you have excess blankspaces or linebreaks in your password.txt file.  If so jonrsharpe comment should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the text document that you have created. If you wrote it by hand and it has multiple lines, it will expect you to put a return at the end of the line. I had this issue a few months ago whilst working on a similar project.
The way to fix this would be to write the text file with python itself. You can do this by using this code:

```
writefile = file("password.txt", 'w')
writefile.writelines(["First Line of File", "\n", "Second Line of File"])
```

This method can be repeated infinitely for any number of lines.

Also, you do not need to indent the define function, as it will throw up an indentation error.

Comment: Yep! This fixed it, thanks for the help. I should have done this earlier. When I was learning about reading and writing from text files I completely ignored the part about /n and thought it wouldn't make a difference. And, I was wrong... Anyway, thats for the help.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of assistance!